# How can I play a JavaScript audio only getUserMedia stream to the user agent?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, getusermedia

I can't figure out how to get an audio only stream (from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) into a real, working audio playback for my users. I would prefer to do everything in native JavaScript (no HTML) but libraries are fine. So, what would I use? Would I just execute

```
new Audio(stream);
```

or would that be not what I want? Very confused, seems like I'm making a simple mistake. I know how to do it with video! Again, prefer audio JS or audio elements only, in this use case we can't show a video in a good place. Stream will always come in audio only due to our constraints. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some experimenting; here's how you do it.

```js
(async () => {
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
    audio.play();
})();
```

WARNING: Obviously this code would play sound from your own microphone; so use a remote stream to avoid very annoying feedback (trust me, I've heard it).

Comment: is there a link to show what you were trying to achieve?